# Responsive website behaving strangely

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm designing a website that has to be responsive.

Using simple

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
}
```

I'm able to make the home page responsive as well as simulate the rest of the pages on my computer by dragging and resizing the browser window.

However, when I test the same link on my phone (Nexus 4), only the home page is responsive. The other pages fail to be responsive.

Link to website: http://bit.ly/rspnsvtst

My css file is rather extensive (about 1400 lines) and I've not added it here. If needed, I'll add it in the edits.

Any clues as to why it's behaving strangely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internal pages have no

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

defined in the `<head>` section: add this meta in every page.

See also this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) for futher reference about the importance of this meta for mobile devices or [this interesting presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wscVOXjIzQ) by Peter-Paul Koch,